# Перенос текста UILabel или UITextField

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Наверное, затасканый вопрос, и я запросто могу нарваться на минусы, но все же: не могу найти, как объяснить Xcode, что нужно перенести текст.

У меня есть `UITextField`, в котором ну слов +-200, задаю я его не через Xib, а хардкодом. Как мне поставить ограничение по ширине, чтобы дойдя до него, слова перенеслись ниже?

Буду благодарен, если подскажете, как сделать это для `UITextField` и `UILabel`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

У класса [`UILabel`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) смотрите свойство [`lineBreakMode`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/lineBreakMode) и соответственно [перечисление видов переноса, которые он поддерживает](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSLineBreakMode) ну и на всякий случай [`numberOfLines`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/numberOfLines).

С `UITextField` перенос невозможен - насколько мне известно, это поле может быть только однострочным.

Для многострочного ввода посмотрите в действии на [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html) - скорее всего вам нужно использовать его. Маленькое замечание: у этого класса, хотя его поля и являются многострочными, отсутствует свойство `lineBreakMode` аналогичное такому в `UILabel`.

Гляньте также соответствующие ссылки на SO:

- [Wrap text in UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068115/wrap-text-in-uitextfield)
- [How to create a multiline UITextfield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345561/how-to-create-a-multiline-uitextfield)
- [UITextView character wrap but not word wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947916/uitextview-character-wrap-but-not-word-wrap)

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: И еще - поправьте UILable в двух местах: в заголовке и в теле вопроса. Правильное написание - UILabel.

Comment: Больше спасибо за очень внятный ответ!

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос и за ответ! 
Небольшое дополнение: не добавлять нижний Constraint, иначе вертикальное выравнивание текста метки будет по центру (https://skalolaskovy.ru/xcode/551-uilabel-vertical-align )